# test empty div in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery code, I want to add a test on the available number **div** in order to see if it's empty or not. If it is the case, I want to remove it. Could anybody help me plz?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#teln_operatorbundle_centrextype_numberrange").change(requestNumber);
});

function requestNumber() {

    // alert("ok");
    $.get(('http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/select/' + $("select#teln_operatorbundle_centrextype_numberrange").val()),
            function(data) {
                $('#availableNumber').html(data);
            }
    );
    if ($('#availableNumber').is(':empty')) {
        $('#availableNumber').remove();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: is there only one div or more ?

Comment: can you have that html in string ?

Comment: No actually @Deepanshu

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the text in the `#availableNumber` div and if empty found remove it this way:

```
if($.trim($('#availableNumber').text()) == '') {
    $('#availableNumber').remove();
}
```

You can use `$.trim()` to remove any whitespaces from the div above.

---

and this should do the trick too:

```
if($('#availableNumber:empty').length > 0){
   $('#availableNumber:empty').remove();
}
```

The above line will remove the `#availableNumber` if found empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
var contents = $('#availableNumber');
if (!contents.children().length) {
    contents.remove();
}
```

Comment: A space would still validate.

Comment: That's because of the fact that some browsers auto-strip when rendering. You can't rely on it :)

Comment: Actually what I don't understand is this: should a div with a space in it should be removed or not? I was aiming to remove the div also when it had a space in it. Maybe I didn't get the OP question.

Answer (score 0):

You can check like

```
if($('#availableNumber').text().length < 1) {
    $('#availableNumber').remove();
}
```

This should cover space also